# How to do qualify for active calls asterisk [ Elastix ]?

Tags: php, scripting, asterisk, sip, elastix

I have been working on sip configuration to do qualify on the level of active calls , but so far no option to do that , and I haven't found any script useful to do just that , if not if there is any command in asterisk CLI to accomplish this task

Regards,

Comment: It is not clear what you really triing to do. Want get number of current calls? QoS info? what?

Comment: @arheops , what I am trying to do is QoS for active calls only , by sending keep alive given a pre-calculated amount of time let's say one second [ only active calls , not as the level of trunk ]

Comment: active call send rtp data 40 times/second. Why you need ENOTHER one packet?

Comment: Use conenction tracking with sip support, via iptables.

Comment: @arheops rtp timeout is not an option since the network might glitch from time to time , but [SIP Option , I think would be more reliable ] , I think it could be better than rtp timeout parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,

I have made it by writing a custom script that gets the active calls and take the call-id from there and send an option message every 5 seconds

Regards,

Comment: Please share your knowledge